# What is the SQL query for returning Ids that contain only one certain value and nothing else?

Tags: sql, database

let's say I have the following entries in a table with two columns:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | F |
| 1 | N |
| 1 | N |
| 2 | F |
| 3 | N |
| 3 | N |
| 3 | N |
| 4 | N |
| 5 | F |
| 5 | N |

I only want to output the Ids that have a value of 'N' and at the same time not the value 'F' in the second column. In this example my output from the query would be the Ids: 3 & 4.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the database supports `EXISITS`, you can check for the existence of a row with the `id` and the value `F`.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Id
FROM mytable m1
WHERE Value = 'N'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE Value = 'F' AND m1.Id = Id)
```